# Why don't we need to install a Bower CLI seperatly?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

As the title says, according to tutorials for example we need to install Grunt and Grunt CLI seperately. I was curious as to why this is not the case with Bower?

Why don't I need to install Bower and a Bower CLI seperatly?